# Mergesorting an object, not sure what goes wrong

Tags: c++11, object, mergesort

So to the question:

I've been trying to apply mergesort on an array of objects that contain 3 ints, in terms of defining who is bigger than the other I'm positive it works right.

My problem is that (I think) it doesn't work well in the recursion bit.

So this is a homework assignment and we weren't asked to use mergesort but I've read about it a few days ago and I'm trying to learn new things,I've successfully applied it on a regular array with just ints but something goes wrong here:

1) the "R" array receives junk values.
2) leftCount's and rightCount's values are smaller than they should be (although it could be because that's how mergesort works as part of the recursion).

I could go back to just using  something simple but I really want to get it right and would appreciate help.

so, the numbers are a date and the isBefore() function checks which one comes first. I checked it and it works fine I can add it if you want me to.

SIZE = 30;
MyDate contains: int day,month,year.
Calendar contains: MyDate array[SIZE].

```
//using mergeSort algorithm
void Calendar::sortDates()
{
    int n = SIZE;
    MergeSort(_dates,n);
    //still need to add 0 - s in the end
}

void Calendar::MergeSort(MyDate* _dates,int n)
{
    int mid, i;
    MyDate *L, *R;

    if (n < 2) return;//base condition for recursion

    mid = n / 2;
    L = new MyDate[mid * sizeof(MyDate)];
    R = new MyDate[(n - mid) * sizeof(MyDate)];


    for (i = 0; i < mid; i++)
    {
        L[i] = _dates[i]; //creating left sub_array
    }

    for (i = mid; i < n; i++) 
        R[i] = _dates[i]; //creating right sub_array

    MergeSort(L, mid);
    MergeSort(R, n - mid);
    Merge(_dates, L, mid, R, n - mid);
}
void Calendar::Merge(MyDate * _dates, MyDate * L, int leftCount, MyDate * R, int rightCount)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
    bool ok = false;
    MyDate max = _dates[0];
    while (i < leftCount && j < rightCount)
    {
        ok = L[i].isBefore(R[j]);
        if (!ok)
        {
            _dates[k++] = L[i++]; 
        }

        else _dates[k++] = R[j++];
    }
    while (i < leftCount)
    _dates[k++] = L[i++];
    while (j < rightCount) 
    _dates[k++] = R[j++];
}
```

Comment: You will never find homework tag here..and regrading the question its very unclear what you are trying to ask..

Comment: Okay, I remember it being a requirement from some post I read...My question is what's wrong with the code, why is it receiving junk values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You allocate an unnecessary amount of space:

```
L = new MyDate[mid * sizeof(MyDate)];
R = new MyDate[(n - mid) * sizeof(MyDate)];
// should be
L = new MyDate[mid];
R = new MyDate[n - mid];
```

And the cause of the right subarray being garbage is probably:

```
for (i = mid; i < n; i++) 
    R[i] = _dates[i];
// should be
for (i = 0; i < n - mid; i++) 
    R[i] = _dates[mid+i];
```

There may be other problems, these are the two I notice at a glance.

Comment: Thanks for the corrections! Although, the second one probably fixed some of it but now it receives even more junk values, anything else you can suggest?

Comment: I am not sure, it is working fine for me with ints. I ninja edited the code right after I posted it, so maybe you missed the my correction to my original answer where I changed `_dates[i]` to `_dates[mid+i]`?

Comment: Okay, so it's working! Yes, I've missed it. Thank you so so much, I've been trying to figure it out for hours! By the way, is there a way I can add all the "null" dates to the end of the array? By that I mean 0/0/0000

Comment: So the user may enter 0/0/0000 dates in the input list, and you want these to appear at the end of the output? It sounds like you would only need to modify the isBefore function.

Comment: I would think so,I added the isBefore function a first condition that checks if a date has zeroes in it, if so return false (it just mixes the area with zeroes)..Instead I made 2 for loops (not nested) that would sort it before starting the merge sort..not optimal but it works. If you have a suggestion I'd love to hear it!

Comment: If you think about it, what I suspect happens (I think I'm getting the hang of merge sort better now but not fully so I might be mistaken). For example, what if L[i] = 0 && R[j] = 0? Nothing happens. So for 3 arbitrary dates and another 2 that are 0 I would get a case of correct sort with one zero at the end (as needed) and the other in a random place. That would only happen if the 0 is in a specific place in the array that would make that situation occur otherwise it works correctly